# Looping through an xml file

Tags: xml, vb.net

I have some xml like so;

```
<PurchaseOrders>
  <Owner ContactId="39" Owner="M Mouse" Owed="1,609.39" WeeklyDeductionRate="10.00" FromMinimumReturn="110.00" DeductionRate="0.0150" TotalDeductions="34.14" TotalToBeReturned="1,575.24">
    <Products ProductId="33" Cost="5.00" Quantity="0.40" />
    <Products ProductId="34" Cost="1.80" Quantity="0.90" />
    <Products ProductId="41" Cost="2.30" Quantity="1.30" />
    <Products ProductId="42" Cost="2.25" Quantity="1.30" />
    <Products ProductId="43" Cost="1.60" Quantity="10.50" />
    <Products ProductId="57" Cost="7.00" Quantity="13.30" />
    <Products ProductId="59" Cost="9.63" Quantity="47.00" />
    <Products ProductId="61" Cost="6.23" Quantity="32.60" />
    <Products ProductId="66" Cost="1.00" Quantity="5.60" />
    <Products ProductId="92" Cost="0.50" Quantity="4.80" />
    <Products ProductId="125" Cost="1.00" Quantity="3.80" />
    <Products ProductId="139" Cost="6.50" Quantity="3.90" />
    <Products ProductId="156" Cost="1.50" Quantity="1.70" />
    <Products ProductId="161" Cost="5.80" Quantity="44.20" />
    <Products ProductId="171" Cost="3.88" Quantity="12.00" />
    <Products ProductId="173" Cost="4.55" Quantity="32.50" />
    <Products ProductId="175" Cost="5.00" Quantity="52.90" />
    <Products ProductId="182" Cost="0.50" Quantity="18.50" />
    <Products ProductId="198" Cost="0.50" Quantity="27.40" />
    <Products ProductId="220" Cost="1.50" Quantity="38.60" />
    <Products ProductId="231" Cost="6.00" Quantity="0.90" />
    <Products ProductId="236" Cost="0.85" Quantity="2.10" />
  </Owner>
  <Owner ContactId="42" Owner="F Flintstone" Owed="710.01" WeeklyDeductionRate="10.00" FromMinimumReturn="110.00" DeductionRate="0.0150" TotalDeductions="20.65" TotalToBeReturned="689.35">
    <Products ProductId="32" Cost="6.00" Quantity="0.50" />
    <Products ProductId="33" Cost="5.00" Quantity="2.00" />
    <Products ProductId="34" Cost="1.80" Quantity="7.80" />
    <Products ProductId="57" Cost="7.00" Quantity="3.10" />
    <Products ProductId="59" Cost="10.00" Quantity="16.30" />
    <Products ProductId="61" Cost="6.60" Quantity="13.90" />
    <Products ProductId="131" Cost="0.90" Quantity="1.70" />
    <Products ProductId="156" Cost="1.50" Quantity="1.50" />
    <Products ProductId="161" Cost="5.80" Quantity="17.40" />
    <Products ProductId="164" Cost="1.10" Quantity="3.10" />
    <Products ProductId="171" Cost="3.80" Quantity="5.70" />
```

My plan has been to loop through the  elements and extract info from its attributes and then run a loop through that Owner's  elements.

To that end I tried the following (adding logging to see what I got back).

```
 Dim doc As New XmlDocument()
        doc.Load(GenerateStreamFromString(SubmissionsEditor.Text))
        Dim elemList As XmlNodeList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Owner")
        Dim pElemList As XmlNodeList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Products")
        For i As Integer = 0 To elemList.Count - 1
            Dim lSupplierId As Integer = CInt(elemList(i).Attributes("ContactId").Value)
            SiAuto.Main.LogInt(NameOf(lSupplierId), lSupplierId)
            For j As Integer = 0 To pElemList.Count - 1
                Dim lProductId As Integer = CInt(pElemList(i).Attributes("ProductId").Value)
                SiAuto.Main.LogInt("Number of Products that will be looped Through", pElemList.Count - 1)
                SiAuto.Main.LogInt(NameOf(lProductId), lProductId)
            Next
        Next
```

I was a little taken aback by the resulting logfile as I was expecting the number of products to be looped through to be of the order of 22. What part of the looping structure might be incorrect?

[image]

Comment: Why not use xpath to parse the file?

Comment: @OldProgrammer  simply because this is a method I've frequently used and in most cases found to both work and be extremely quick.

Comment: Need to test that lSupplierId = 39.  Get ElementsByTagName will enumerate through all children starting with doc.  You could use elemList.GetElementsByTagName("Products")

Comment: @jdweng  As in elemList.GetElementsByTagName("Products").Count - 1?  The compiler tells me that GetElementsByTagName is not a member of XmlNodeList.

Comment: "i" is index for elemList but you're using it for pElementList. Doesn't makes sense. If you properly name your index, you might see it.

Comment: Need to convert XmlNodeList to Xmlelement : Dim elem1List As XmlElement = elemList(0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop is actually running through *all product elements*, as your code details no connection between an owner and its products. If you prefer your current approach to XPath, you should select all the product elements which are children of your current Owner element:

```
Dim doc As New XmlDocument()
        doc.Load(GenerateStreamFromString(SubmissionsEditor.Text))
        Dim elemList As XmlNodeList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Owner")
        For i As Integer = 0 To elemList.Count - 1
        Dim pElemList As XmlNodeList = elemList(i).SelectNodes("//Products")
            Dim lSupplierId As Integer = CInt(elemList(i).Attributes("ContactId").Value)
            SiAuto.Main.LogInt(NameOf(lSupplierId), lSupplierId)
            For j As Integer = 0 To pElemList.Count - 1
                Dim lProductId As Integer = CInt(pElemList(j).Attributes("ProductId").Value)
                SiAuto.Main.LogInt("Number of Products that will be looped Through", pElemList.Count - 1)
                SiAuto.Main.LogInt(NameOf(lProductId), lProductId)
            Next
        Next
```

If you'd prefer to use XPath and For Each loops in your implementation (which helps avoid bad indexing typos), your code might look like:

```
        Dim doc As New XmlDocument()
        doc.Load(GenerateStreamFromString(SubmissionsEditor.Text))
        Dim elemList As XmlNodeList = doc.SelectNodes("//Owner")
        For Each elem As XmlNode In elemList
            Dim pElemList As XmlNodeList = elem.SelectNodes("//Products")
            Dim lSupplierId As Integer = CInt(elem.Attributes("ContactId").Value)
            SiAuto.Main.LogInt(NameOf(lSupplierId), lSupplierId)
            For Each pElem As XmlNode In pElemList
                Dim lProductId As Integer = CInt(pElem.Attributes("ProductId").Value)
                SiAuto.Main.LogInt("Number of Products that will be looped Through", pElemList.Count - 1)
                SiAuto.Main.LogInt(NameOf(lProductId), lProductId)
            Next
        Next
```

Comment: pElemList(i) should be pElemList(j) which I think is one of the problem he is having. Could also be changed to a For Each in this case.

Comment: @wibbler  Once I'd corrected my own typo (pointed out in the last comment below my question by the_lotus and then removed the two leading forwardslashes from "//Products" this worked a treat .  Thanks.   Just as a matter of interest how would you have done this using XPath?

Comment: I've updated my answer with an XPath and For Each loop version of the solution. http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp is a good resource for understanding XPath syntax and how it may be useful.